# How to figure a text box set of characters into a text box figure 2 effect?

Tags: html, css, input

[image]

[image]

Who can help me to modify the CSS code to complete the effect of figure 1 to figure 2,I want to figure a text box set as figure 2 styles, I should how to modify the CSS code.
    The following is a CSS and HTML code.

```
 .username{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 280px;
        height:48px;
        background-color: green;

    }

    .blanline{
        width: 280px;
        height:23px;
        background-color: #F0FFFF;
    }

    .password{
        width: 280px;
        height:48px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    div input,button{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 25px;

    }
    <div class="username">
                                <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="blanline"></div>
                            <div class="password">
                                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                            </div>
```

Who can help me ,i will be grate for you.

Comment: Not able to understand your question. You want to add some default text to the input?

Comment: Are you using HTML5?
You want Placeholder string,correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `placeholder` in the `input` tag.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="text here">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="text here>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just asking about a `placeholder`:  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt1nmt7t/1/)

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="placeholder here">
```

And to style the placeholder text:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML code:

```
<div class="username">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="blanline"></div>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.username{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 280px;
    height:48px;
    background-color: green;

}

.blanline{
    width: 280px;
    height:23px;
}

.password{
    width: 280px;
    height:48px;
    background-color: green;
}
div input,button{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 25px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways:
 
1. You can use the HTML5 placeholder attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text." />
```

2.You can do this for webkit:

```
#username::-webkit-input-placeholder::before {
    color:#666;
    content:"Username";
}

#password::-webkit-input-placeholder::before {
    color:#666;
    content:"Password";
}
```

Second may not work in all browsers better go for first.